# Arithmetic Operators on String after converting them, SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have two strings, `boughtString` and `profitString`, which I am getting from the user (via the user). After, I am trying to multiply `100/95` and `(boughtString+profitString)`.The way I do this is (and show)

`Text("\(Int(Int(100/95)*Int(Int(boughtString)+Int(profitString))))")`

But this doesn't seem to be understood properly by Swift, what am I doing wrong? I am doing this through SwiftUI

Comment: `Int(boughtString)` is an Optional. You need to unwrap it. — In general, do not make "thick" expressions like this. Work one step at a time. Expressions like yours are hard to debug (or understand).

Comment: I tried doing it in "steps" but it seems that you can't do calculations inside a view in SwiftUI. Would you mind suggesting something please? @matt

Answer (score 1):

`Int(string)` returns an *optional* `Int` which must be unwrapped to be used.  Since this is SwiftUI which doesn't like iterative code in the View builders, a good way to handle this would be to make [*read-only computed properties*](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#ID259) that turn `boughtString` and `profitString` into `Int`s.

Also, `Int(100 / 95)` is just going to be `1`, because integer division discards the fractional part.  I assume you don't just want to multiply by `1` because that will do nothing useful.  Multiplying first by `100` and then dividing by `95` will give you the result I think you're looking for.

Here is an example of how this might be done:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var boughtString = ""
    @State private var profitString = ""

    // Use nil-coalescing operator ?? to provide default values if
    // the String is not a valid Int
    var bought: Int { Int(boughtString) ?? 0 }
    var profit: Int { Int(profitString) ?? 0 }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Bought", text: $boughtString)
            TextField("Profit", text: $profitString)
            Text("\(100 * (bought + profit) / 95)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Those are computed properties.  Every time the property `bought` is accessed, the code in the closure `{ Int(boughtString) ?? 0 }` runs and returns a value.

Comment: Why not simply * 0.95

Comment: @LeoDabus, you know Swift.  It's never as simple as just `* 0.95`.  You need to make sure both operands are float types, and then OP wants an `Int` result so you have to convert back. `Text("\(Int(Double(bought + profit) / 0.95))")` gives the same result.  I was just keeping things in the integer world.